# PhoneGap Geolocation on iOS always gets cached GPS - why?

Tags: jquery, ios, geolocation, phonegap

I am running this on iOS in PhoneGap:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess,geolocationError, { 
maximumAge: 1000, timeout: 10000 , enableHighAccuracy: true } );
```

If I then move a few miles away, open the app and run geolocation, it shows me where I was before. It doesn't get the new location. When I then open Google Maps, for example ..and then run geolocation again, it shows the correct position.

In other words, I need to open another app that then gets the correct location for my app to get this correct location too.

It's almost like iOS is lying to me and returning me a cached location instead of getting a new one.

I even tried `watchPosition` looping and it's also returning me the old cached GPS.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Exact same problem, though I was not setting any options:

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
```

Opening and closing the app, restarting the phone, nothing, the GPS was identical down to the 14th decimal place so was obviously cached, regardless of how many miles the phone had moved.

The only difference was the maximumAge, which I set to 0 (even though 0 is supposed to be the default):

```
var geoOptions = {
 maximumAge : 0,
 enableHighAccuracy: true
};
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoOptions)
```

This only occurred on a single IOS phone, the other IOS phones worked fine.  Setting the options as I did above fixed it, which does not indicate anything related to what caused this to happen originally.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?  I have exact same problem too.